# I tried to make an array of strings and now I have an issue with my code which I don't know how to fix

Tags: c

I'm trying to make an array of strings by using pointers but for some reason (which I hope you would know) the program is crashing after I type the second string. I have been trying for hours to find what's wrong with this code and I'm hoping for your help! During debugging, after I realloced the input it says "error reading characters of string." Here is the code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>


int main()
{
    char **input = (char **)calloc(1, sizeof(char)), ch;
    *input = (char *)calloc(1, sizeof(char));
    int size = 1,sizeinput=1,current = 0,currentarr=0,i=0,j=0;
    while (i<5)
{

    printf("please enter a word\n");
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    while (ch != '\n')
    {
        *(input+i) = (char*)realloc(*(input+i), (size++)*sizeof(char));
        *(*(input + i) + j++) = ch;
        scanf("%c", &ch);
    }

    *(*(input + i) + j) = '\0';
    j = 0;
    input = (char**)realloc(input, (sizeinput++)*sizeof(char*));
    i++;
    }
    free(input);
}
```

Comment: Why do you write `*(input+i)` rather than `input[i]`?

Comment: only because our proffesor told us to write like that

Comment: @omri Please disregard your professors advice in this matter.

Comment: @FUZxxl although I do see your point, I also see pedagogic value in understanding that array indexing is just pointer addition. As long as the students know it's just pedagogic :)

Comment: yeah i know :) , i'm aware that the indexing can be done in various ways and he explained it to us as well, he just asked for it for us to show him we know what we do with the pointers

Comment: @omri Just remember, in production code always use `a[b]` instead of `*(a + b)` or your project partners are going to hate you.

Comment: lol thanks, i will keep that in mind :)

Comment: `size` too small by 1.

Comment: `realloc(*(input+i), (size++)*sizeof(char))` does not allocate space for the null character.

Comment: Also `size` may need to be reset within `while (i < 5) {`

Comment: regarding lines like: `char **input = (char **)calloc(1, sizeof(char))`  1) in C, when calling the memory allocation family of functions, do not cast the returned value.  It is already a `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code and creates headaches when debugging/maintaining the code.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: When calling `realloc()`, never assign directly into the target pointer.  Rather assign to a temporary pointer, then check (!=NULL) that temporary pointer and if not NULL then assign to the target pointer.  Otherwise, when `realloc()` fails, the original pointer will be overlayed with NULL, resulting in a memory leak because the original pointer value cannot be passed to `free()`

Comment: the expression `sizeof( char )` is, by definition always 1.  multiplying anything by 1 has not effect.  Using that expression (multiplied by something else) in the parameter to a memory allocation function just clutters the code, has no effect, and adds headaches when debugging/maintaining the code.  It also makes the code harder to read/understand

Comment: The posted code fails to cleanly compile, resulting in the compiler raising 4 warnings.  When compiling, always enable all the warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` I also use: `-std=c99 -Wconversion`. )  Then fix those warnings.

Comment: for readability/understandability by us humans and for ease of documentation by tools like `doxygen`, please follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.

Comment: for readability, please consistently indent the code.  Suggest 4 spaces after every opening brace '{' and unindent before every closing brace '}'.

Comment: regarding this line: `char **input = (char **)calloc(1, sizeof(char))`  This allocates a single char for what is expected.defined to be an array of pointers to char.  Suggest: `char **input = calloc(1, sizeof(char*))`

Comment: this line: `*(input+i) = (char*)realloc(*(input+i), (size++)*sizeof(char));` is not correct because 1) it does not allow for the NUL termination byte I.E. the char array should be 2 bytes long before inserting the first byte.  It is a poor programming practice to use side effects.  suggest: `size++; char *temp =  realloc(*(input+i), size); if( NULL == temp ) { // handle realloc error, cleanup, exit } *(input+i) = temp;`

Comment: Regarding this line: `*(*(input + i) + j++) = ch;`  do not use side effects.  Suggest: `*(*(input + i) + j) = ch; j++;`

Comment: when calling `scanf()`, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  In the current scenario, any returned value other than 1 is an error

Comment: regarding this line: `input = (char**)realloc(input, (sizeinput++)*sizeof(char*));`  it is poor programming practice to use side effects.  And the sizeinput is being incremented too late (postincrement)  suggest: `sizeinput++; input = realloc(input, (sizeinput)*sizeof(char*));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is happening due to a reallocation happening in non-allocated memory. Consider your original code. When you call `realloc` for the first time, you call it for `*(input + i)`, which was previously allocated because `i` is zero at this point. This allocation happens in the second line of your `main` function. The problem is that you never allocate for position 1, which you try to (re!)allocate later. This fixes it:

```
int main()
{
    char **input = (char **)calloc(1, sizeof(char)), ch;

    // Don't do it here
    //*input = (char *)calloc(1, sizeof(char));

    int size = 1,sizeinput=1,current = 0,currentarr=0,i=0,j=0;

    while (i<5)
    {
        printf("please enter a word\n");
        scanf("%c", &ch);

        // Do it here instead
        *(input + i) = (char *)calloc(1, sizeof(char));

        while (ch != '\n')
        {
            // Now this reallocation is actually being given something that was allocated before
            *(input+i) = (char*)realloc(*(input+i), (size++)*sizeof(char));
            *(*(input + i) + j++) = ch;
            scanf("%c", &ch);
        }

        *(*(input + i) + j) = '\0';
        j = 0;
        input = (char**)realloc(input, (sizeinput++)*sizeof(char*));
        i++;
    }

    free(input);
}
```

There are several other issues with this, but as my first suggestion would be to take a different approach I'll leave other issues off the discussion. Let me know if you are interested, anyway.

Note: This causes one extra reallocation per loop. But as I said, it's just a quick fix.

Comment: I'm glad. Happy coding :)

Comment: You allocate the wrong amount of memory in the first `calloc`

Comment: You write the `'\0'` out of bounds of the allocated space

Comment: This code is pretty badly laid out - many lines are repeated (e.g. the two `scanf` lines, `j = 0` etc.), and obfuscated versions of pointer access are used

Comment: @M.M the code is as originally posted by the OP. All I did was fix the error the OP asked for and, as mentioned in my answer, several other issues exist here (hint: you're not half the way there. There are memory leaks and I/O problems). However, as I said, I focused on solving the problem. If you want to suggest other fixes feel free to do so.

Answer (score 3):

`(char **)calloc(1, sizeof(char))`

should be

`(char **)calloc(1, sizeof(char*))`

Also, after you reallocate `input`, the last element is an uninitialized pointer! Add this at the end of the loop, so it points to something useful and which you can reallocate later:

```
input[sizeinput - 1] = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
```

Cosmetic issues:

There's no need to cast the results of `calloc` and `realloc` - although doing so won't prevent your program from working, it does make it uglier.

Also, you can use `input[i]` instead of `*(input + i)` and `input[i][j]` instead of `*(*(input + i) + j)` - again, it won't affect how your program executes, but it can make it easier to read.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but unfortunatly its stiil doesn't worked, it's just keep getting stuck after I type the second string

Comment: @omri What does "it's just keep getting stuck" mean?

Comment: the program is freezing, like its out of the boundries of the array

Comment: By _freezing_, do you mean that it crashes or that it keeps prompting for values?

Comment: Maybe provide a sample session

Comment: it just freezes and then crashes, I do know that it probably happen because of the "realloc" in the end, after this realloc, when i check the value of "input" durring debug it says "error reading characters of string."

Comment: try to run the code maybe you'll understand the problem better

Comment: I have, but I believe the reallocation problem happens in the first realloc, inside the while loops, not the last. But I'm still looking into it

Answer (score 0):

the following code incorporates the comments, compiles cleanly, uses a function: `cleanup()` which I did not define, however, `cleanup()` will pass each word to `free()` then pass the 'array of pointers to char' to `free()`

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include <conio.h>

// prototypes
void cleanup( char ** input );

int main()
{
    char **input = calloc(1, sizeof(char*));
    char ch;
    *input = calloc(1, sizeof(char));
    size_t size = 1;
    size_t sizeinput=1;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    while (i<5)
    {

        printf("please enter a word\n");
        if( 1 != scanf("%c", &ch) )
        {
            perror( "scanf failed" );
            cleanup( input );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        while (ch != '\n')
        {
            size++;
            char *temp = realloc(*(input+i), size);
            if( NULL == temp)
            {
                perror( "realloc for word failed" );
                cleanup( input );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }
            *(input+i) = temp;

            *(*(input + i) + j) = ch;
            j++;

            if( 1 != scanf("%c", &ch) )
            {
                perror( "scanf failed" );
                cleanup( input );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

        }

        // NUL terminate word
        *(*(input + i) + j) = '\0';
        j = 0;

        sizeinput++;
        char** lineTemp = realloc(input, sizeinput*sizeof(char*));
        if( NULL == lineTemp )
        {
            perror( "realloc failed" );
            cleanup( input );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        input = lineTemp;
        i++;
    }
    free(input);
}
```